What are these connectors called?
I found these 2 extra unsoldered connectors/pins on my motherboard, and I'm trying to figure out what are they.
In the first picture there is a main matrix like connector in the middle, and there is peripheral power supply connectors (the 2 pin ones) near it. Is it a eMMC connector or what is it?
The second picture showed a 25x2 pin connector that already had power suppliers installed near it, what is that?



No connectors; two empty places for optional IC:s
and
PL14, PL15, PL16 - "L" is for Inductor, "P" for Power version of one such. So those looks as actual components already mounted there. The relatively large solder blobs also indicates "high power"

could you explain a bit more? You mean both picture are not connectors? Cause I acually has seens a connector been placed on the pin on the second picture.

Q in Q7 does not usually indicate a connector position. shrug. This may then be something very special for that particular manufacturer. But JSEV might then be the text to actually look at, I can't tell what that would indicate. A larger connector usually has some kind of mechanical locking mechanism (for the actual connector), which is not present here.

Disclaimer: casual electronics hobbyist with no electronics industry experience:
Those are not connectors in the normal sense. Those look to me like the "footprints" of integrated circuits whose presence is only needed for some variations of the final product.
The footprints consist of a set of bare copper pads that have not been coated with solder-mask and so have had solder applied when the board was passed through a solder-bath to solder the populated components. Either that or the mask for automated solder-paste placement was common to several product variants.
Standard footprints often have names such as QFP and SOIC along with numbers that indicate number of positions etc.
Older dual-in-line (DIL) ICs with 0.1" pin-spacing sometimes had DIL sockets with pin positions the same as the IC-pin positions or had Dupont style header pins soldered in to construct an IC-socket in order to make the ICs more easily replaceable. This is now much less common than in prior millenia. However your second photo looks to me like a more dense pin-spacing than 0.1" and I don't think those denser pin spacings have IC-sockets in normal mass-market products. If they did, I think they are more likely to have a footprint designed for the socket and not for the IC.
So no connectors visible, just a place for an optional IC to be directly soldered.
